# After logging in, being redirected to https://site/favicon.ico

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Something very odd is happening with my ASP.NET application where I've created a login portal, and whenever the login is complete about 75% of the time I get redirected to favicon.ico.

For example, here is the login page that I sign in to:

[image]

Then after I enter my e-mail and password, I somehow end up here:

[image]

The ReturnUrl is being used as a redirect after login, and %2f being the forward slash, it should take the user to the default.  Instead it somehow ends up at favicon.ico.

I really don't understand this, especially since it does not happen all of the time.  I do see the behavior across Firefox, Chrome, and IE11.  In the cases where it does not happen, I land on `https://172.16.0.20`, the default.

Here is how I route in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Models.LoginViewModel login)
{
    User u = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (authProvider.Authenticate(login.Email, login.Password, login.RememberMe, out u))
        {
            return Redirect((TempData["ReturnUrl"] == null) ? Url.Action("Index", "Home") : (string)TempData["ReturnUrl"]);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password");
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is my only route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

---

*EDIT*:  From using Fiddler, as suggested, it looks like at some point it tries to get favicon.ico and the server responds with its location, changing the ReturnUrl:

```
GET http://172.16.0.20/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.0.20
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=gp1osbxvm5uawvfmsu3is5db
Connection: keep-alive


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2ffavicon.ico
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 15 Dec 2014 15:51:29 GMT
Content-Length: 156
```

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: OK, no need to downvote for it.  I added the routing

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and put appropriate breakpoints in your code so you can find out at what point you're redirected.

Comment: Ran Fiddler, added part of the log

Answer (score 1):

The reason `favicon.ico` is called is because that is the standard thumbnail image url. Browsers use the image data to populate the little website logo in the left of your chrome tabs (other browsers may put the logo elsewhere).

Additionally, if you don't specify a mobile-optimized logo, when you save a web page to your home screen in iOS (and probably android too), they will use the `favicon.ico` as the icon. Additionally, different browsers have different rules for how often they refresh the file so you can't really predict when it will get requested, and all the major browsers check it.

You should solve this problem generally. That is, if your code sticks the last requested URL into the `TempData["ReturnUrl"]`, you will also have issues if a user happens to request any images as well from a tag like

```
<img src="/someOtherReturnUrl.jpg" />
```

So one solution is to change the place where you populate TempData["ReturnUrl"] to only store if it's a `Controller` that is serving a page as opposed to a static file. There are ways to check this in an `HttpModule` or in an `ActionFilter` which is probably what you're using.

Alternatively, and this is probably simpler to do, change your code to be:

```
if (authProvider.Authenticate(login.Email, login.Password, login.RememberMe, out u))
{
    return Redirect((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])) 
        ? Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]
        : Url.Action("Index", "Home");
}
```

Because it looks like your login page is of the url pattern: `/account/login?ReturnUrl=SomeUrl` and the query string is more consistent than whatever the previous request happened to be. Seriously, on the web you cannot guarantee request order, ever. (or at least it's usually a bad idea to assume a rational order because users and browsers do all sorts of wacky and inventive things).